# What do you call words like "wanna"?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for words like "wanna" or "gonna" which have been shortened from their originals of "want to" and "going to"?

Comment: Informal expressions,  slang expressions. https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/node/403

Comment: But (to my surprise) becoming more standard nowadays.  Found even in formal writing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are called *contractions*.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. The majority of this answer is a direct quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)). While corroboration is fine and encouraged, quotes must be preceded by > and correctly cited [and linked, if online]. I've done this here.

Answer (score 0):

- gonna /ˈgɒnə  / informal ▸ (contraction) going to: so what you gonna do
  now?
- wanna /ˈwɒnə  / informal ▸ (contraction) want to; want a: you wanna
  know how low I've stooped? I wanna guitar.
  [OxfordLivingDictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wanna)

Comment: That's not OED you've linked to, mahmud. It's a different Oxford dictionary.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, Yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing out the mistake. It's OLD!

Comment: I use the abbreviation ODO, which I think is the one the Meta people advise us to use.